# How to protect a public accessible API?

Tags: rest, architecture, api-design

I'm working in creating a FORM (kind of survey) to get user input, **any user** who visited the website can provide me information. This would means, the API is actually public accessible to anyone without any token or session (basically nothing)

I want to **prevent people** from getting my endpoint and create thousand/millions of requests **(SPAM) to flood my service and database**. I've tried to look over Stackoverflow and some post in medium, it's interesting that I don't find much about this.

Some said:

- bundle my website as an hybrid app, supply accessToken to only "trusted device" for firing my api **(but this is a pure webapp)**
- creating custom header and identify the header from my web server **(hmm..?)**
- use CAPTCHA **(this will only stop people spamming via the GUI, but spamming via script still possible)**

Is this simply no better way to secure, since it's public?
Any thoughts to share?

Answer (score 0):

have you read about Request Queue?
it might help you solve the issue

[source 1](https://hackernoon.com/limiting-your-api-requests-the-right-way-9608b661a0ce)

[source 2](https://nordicapis.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-api-rate-limiting/)

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for the information. By default API Gateway from AWS has throttling in placed.. hence I'm not actually keen to further enhance on this. What I concern more is, anyone who knows how to get your endpoint can simply POST and SPAM you.